# New kernel compilation on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, kernel, kernel-panic

I'm trying to compile and install kernel 3.2.9 for CentOS 5.6.
I compiled new kernel and installed kernel modules:

```
make && make modules_install
```

I also created new initrd image:

```
mkinitrd initrd-3.2.9 3.2.9
```

I copied kernel-3.2.9, initrd-3.2.9 and System.map-3.2.9 to the /boot directory and edited grub.conf file:

```
title kernel-3.2.9
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /kernel-3.2.9 ro root=LABEL=/ rhgb quiet
        initrd /initrd-3.2.9
```

During boot I got a kernel panic with the following error:

```
could not find filesystem /dev/root
```

What I did wrong?

Comment: It could be that you do not have the right hardware drivers compiled in your new kernel. Did you simply use your old kernel config and added/removed a few things? Or did you use a default config and made a custom kernel from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem by myself:
I added `CONFIG_SYSFS_DEPRECATED_V2=y` to the .config file as described here https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=23627&forum=37&post_id=97305#forumpost97305
and it solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

A better way to install the new kernel is to use:

```
$ make install
```

This will copy the needed files and edit your grub configuration to be able to boot the new kernel.

Also, you may have made some mistake during kernel configuration `make menuconfig`. You can look at the existing kernel config files under `/boot/config-<kernel-version>`. For a simple solution, you can start with a configuration similar to the current one and then make the needed changes if any.

Comment: I suppose even better way is to make kernel's `rpm` package and install it.